# Copying one Xelement in to another and then Manipulating the newer one is affecting the older also

Tags: c#, xelement

I am making one Xelement from another.

But when I am manipulating the new Xelement, it is changing the earlier one also.

```
private bool myFunction(List<XElement> jobList)
{
   List<XElement> tempJobList = new List<XElement>(jobList);
   foreach (XElement elements in tempJobList)
  {
    elements.Attribute("someattribute").Remove();
  }
}
```

Now here , after this if when I will check "jobList" , its attribute is also getting removed.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are doing is adding the same element from the original `jobList` to the new `tempJobList` so both lists are pointing at the same dataset. This means that when you manipulate an element you are changing it on both lists.

If you really want a separate object then you need to clone the element before adding it to the temporary list.

```
private bool myFunction(List<XElement> jobList)
{
    List<XElement> tempJobList = new List<XElement>();
    foreach (var element in jobList)
    {
        // Take a copy
        var tempElement = new XElement(element);
        tempJobList.Add(tempElement);
    }

    foreach (XElement elements in tempJobList)
    {
        elements.Attribute("someattribute").Remove();
    }
}
```